# Restrict object to several types

Tags: c#, object, type-conversion

I need to hold an object in class that is restricted to be either a string or a double. How to do it stylistically right? I came up with idea to create a enum with possible types and two methods for each type to set the field.

```cs
public class Operand
{
    /// <summary> Possible types of operand </summary>
    public enum TYPE
    {
        /// <summary> Number </summary>
        Numeric,
        /// <summary> Parameter </summary>
        Parameter,
        /// <summary> Invalid </summary>
        None
    }

    /// <summary> Type of operand </summary>
    public TYPE Type { private set; get; } = TYPE.None;

    /// <summary> Value of operand: double or string </summary>
    public object Value { private set; get; } = null;

    /// <summary> Set the parametric operand </summary>
    public void Set(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Type = TYPE.Parameter;
    }

    /// <summary> Set the numeric operand </summary>
    public void Set(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Type = TYPE.Numeric;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question about the Visual Studio 2019 application, so I have removed your tag.

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: Do you really need to have one object for both string and numeric values? Maybe a better way is to create two fields of different types to avoid boxing/unboxing

Comment: I am re-writing my old C++ project, in which for this purpose I used 'union', and I simply don't know if there is a more simple way to do it in C#, maybe with ```where Value : double, string``` or smth. Yes, I want to hold them in one object for convenience.

Comment: C# doesn't have unions, but you can emulate them with various patterns of structs, such as building your own variation of the proposed [Variant](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28882) struct.

Comment: Issue is this : String is a Class and Double is a Struct. One of them is nullable and the other one is not. You can not restrict type for both condition at the same time with generic constraint. So you should use methods overloading like you did or in one method check the type of object and throw exception or anything else like my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value with one method like this:

```
public void Set(object value)
{
    if (value is String)
    {
        // Type string
    }
    else if (value is Double)
    {
        // type double
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this would allow other (invalid) types to be used. The overloading approach by OP is cleaner.

Comment: That's not a problem, I can add 'else' and throw an exception, or add check for 'null'

Comment: Of course you could, but is a runtime exception really what you want? With the overloading approach, that would be avoided completely. Nothing is being achieved by using a single method; quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the solution with two different fields for values. This way we avoid boxing and unboxing when the value is double. It's less laconic and requires manual check of Type field, but saves recources when double type is used

```
public class Operand
{
    /// <summary> Possible types of operand </summary>
    public enum TYPE
    {
        /// <summary> Number </summary>
        Numeric,
        /// <summary> Parameter </summary>
        Parameter,
        /// <summary> Invalid </summary>
        None
    }

    /// <summary> Type of operand </summary>
    public TYPE Type { private set; get; } = TYPE.None;

    public string StringValue { private set; get; }
    public double DoubleValue { private set; get; }

    /// <summary> Set the parametric operand </summary>
    public void Set(string value)
    {
        StringValue = value;
        Type = TYPE.Parameter;
    }

    /// <summary> Set the numeric operand </summary>
    public void Set(double value)
    {
        DoubleValue = value;
        Type = TYPE.Numeric;
    }
}
```